# How to compare two integer number without using if-else and Equality and Relational Operators

Tags: compare

When I was have interview, A Interviewer ask me a question which how to compare two numbers without using if-else statement and Equality and Relational Operators.

I hope get a solution for me. thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on the programming language. Usually you need a comparision operator of course, because you want to know whether the values are equal. Some languages however have comparision functions instead, such as `a.equals(b)`, which would be a possible solution. Other langages treat numbers like booleans, with zero meaning false, so `if(a-b) ...` would be possible, if ugly. But these are exceptions.

Comment: I tought the Interviewer asked me that question for logical thinking